# Cannot center text in a Android Button

Tags: android, button, center, gravity

Here's my problem, when i user a Button widget with a .9png as it's background, user gravity="center", the text cannot be centered in this widget. But if i use a TextView instead of Button, with the same png, it'll be OK.

try serval times with 10+ types of mobile phones.

i think R.style makes it wrong. But how?

Thanks

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/send_reminder_notice"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/ds220"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/ds80"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_dialog_confirm"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/send_msg"
            android:textColor="@color/cp_cont_e"
            android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize32" />
```

Comment: can you show your 9-patch image?

Comment: not enough reputation :( but i'm sure the 9-patch image is ok. Just cannot get the answer from the source code.

Comment: Got the answer, customized ROM caused the problem.